# DRF - how to return SerializerMethodField() value in json response

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How to return SerializerMethodField() field value as a json reponse in APIView?

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if i understand the question correctly but
you don't return SerializerMethodField() value as json reponse in APIView directly,

SerializerMethodField() is to be used inside the serializer as it shows in the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

after

you can use the serializer in the view as show [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class UsersList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```